# Connecting an external mysql database to django application and querying it

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-views

I need to pull data from an external MySQL database to my application. I have added the below lines to my databases dictionary in settings.py file.

```
'cust': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'cust_data',
        'HOST': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    }
```

Is the engine name right? I have added all other details.

Now is this it? How can I get the data from this database now? Can I simply use an SQL query in my applications views.py?

Now when I enter shell using below command

```
python manage.py shell
```

When I execute a query to the MySQL database, it doesn't work. I am sure I am missing something here.

I am stuck here, what am I doing wrong here? How can I run a command to access data from a particular table in the above DB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your external MySQL database does not map to your Django models. In that case you have to use **django.db.connection** object to connect the database and execute the raw SQL query directly. You can use the query result in views.py but it is best to consider whether views.py is the right place to perform the query action.

To test the query in python shell you can try in this way:

```
>>> from django.db import connections
>>> cursor = connections['cust'].cursor() # Replace 'cust' to other defined databases if necessary.
>>> cursor.execute("YOUR SQL QUERY HERE")
>>> cursor.fetchall()
```

For the method `fetchall()` it should return your result in tuple form.

You can refer more information in the official site from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Comment: This looks perfect, so once after configuring my settings.py, can I directly use the above lines of code as mentioned by Lee? Or should I need to configure something else?

Comment: Yes. You can try the code as mentioned above in the shell (shell by the command `python manage.py shell`) to see if it can get the result from your database. If it returns the expected result you can simply use the same code in the py file.

Answer (score 1):

The constant variable is wrong. You have to declare the `DATABASES` variable.

In your settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'myhost'            
    }
}
```

Just replace the placeholders with the correct values.

Comment: I think you are mistaken here, I am using multiple databases for my application, I already have a default db set and this is my second database. Refer this link for detailed documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/